# Constraint to column in MySQL that if value entered goes negative, It keeps it to 0

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

Is there a way that I can put a constraint on the value of the row being inserted.
If the value is below negative, the column just ignores the value and keeps it to 0.

Suppose value coming in is '-2' and the column is already on 1, then instead of updating to -1, it keeps it to 0.

Comment: In MySQL you would need to use a trigger for this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a trigger in general to handle this.  However, if you are issuing the `update`, then you can use logic in the update:

```
update t
    set cnt = greatest(cnt + $value, 0)
    where id = $id;
```